# Material UI <IconButton> not showing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-button), and I have the following:

```
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
<IconButton iconClassName="muidocs-icon-custom-github" tooltip="bottom-right" tooltipPosition="bottom-right" />
```

When I am testing the tooltip, the icons are not showing, but the tooltip is showing on hover. Can someone help me create an example? Am I missing the icon URL?

Comment: Did you setup the icon fonts? [http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web)

Comment: yah i use <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"> link in my index html page

Answer (score 3):

It seems that's an issue with Material-UI docs. Check this [Link](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/1265) for more details

If you want to place github icon then you can try using SVG Icon. It seems you have to include google material icons stylesheet in your index.html to make it work.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Generally if we want to use svg icons I do it below way.

```
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Remove from 'material-ui/svg-icons/Content/remove';

<IconButton tooltip="Hide" style={{float: 'right'}}  iconStyle={{marginTop: -25, color: myTheme.color}} onClick={this.removeMinus}>
   <Remove color=“red” />
</IconButton>
```

Comment: <Remove/>  those kind of icons have problem everytime i am take material-ui/svg-icons/Content/home or something its did not showing..

Comment: Hoo yeah sorry you have to add color to the svg icon. I added color prop to <Remove color=“red” />. For any Svg icon that you import add color and I am sure you will be able to see icon. I edited my post please check.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `<IconButton>` has a child component that is an icon. In your example it is not rendering anything on the screen (unless you hover) because it has no icon reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is not correct, if you want to use IconButton, you should
has an instance icon inside the IconButton, the code like this:

```js
<IconButton>
  <DeleteIcon />
</IconButton>
```